# Mass assign object_id to objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have two classes: `Schedule` and `Interaction` and they look the following:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interactions

end

class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :schedule_id

  has_one :schedule

end
```

The migrations look like this:

```
class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :schedules do |t|
      t.timestamps

    end
  end
end


class CreateInteractions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :interactions do |t|
      t.integer :schedule_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I do this:

```
irb(main):003:0> interaction_high_1 = Interaction.create()
irb(main):003:0> interaction_high_2 = Interaction.create()
irb(main):003:0> interaction_high_3 = Interaction.create()
irb(main):003:0> interaction_high_4 = Interaction.create()
irb(main):003:0> interaction_high_5 = Interaction.create()

irb(main):003:0> schedule1 = Schedule.create(:name => "high1").interactions << interaction_high_1, interaction_high_2, interaction_high_3, interaction_high_4, interaction_high_5
```

only `Interaction_high_1` gets the designated **schedule_id** and for the rest it's just **nul**

Can anybody tell me why this is and how I might fix it?

Thanks for an answer!!

Comment: first of all, you are supposed to have interaction `belongs_to :schedule`, otherwise the foreign key won't get saved. After fixing that bug in the model file, try again, although i don't know if this is going to work.

Comment: thanks! i already tried this and it doesn't fix the problem. also the interaction really doesn't belong to the schedule so i think has_one is right. i think when you use the belongs_to association, the key is generated automatically, with has_one it has to be generated manually but it still works afaik

Comment: you cant have a `has one` to `has many` relationship. the foreign key won't be saved anywhere.

Comment: thanks, allright i believe you;-) but i'm not sure what you mean, as i can see the foreign key -being schedule_id- in my database (?)

Comment: really?! that's not how active record should work

Comment: with the method stated below it still works with has_one.. also i read this here: http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/activerecord_has_many.html

but as i said you have to generate the key manually, but it still gets assigned

Comment: oh okay. But what happens when you do `@interaction.schedule?`

Comment: i don't really know as i have no clue what this does..;-) but i can test it if you tell me how

Comment: make a instance of a interaction like this: `@schedule1 = Schedule.create(:name => "high1")` and  `@interaction = @schedule1.interactions.create`. Then try to get the schedule of that interaction like this: `@interaction.schedule`. What does it return? Try it in your console

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: schedules.interaction_id: ;-) u where right, thanks!

Comment: glad you posted your question and glad we solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the Interactions without associating them to a Schedule.  Just appending them later won't do what you need.  Do it like this instead:

```
schedule1 = Schedule.create(:name => "high1")

1...5.times do
  schedule1.interactions.create
end
```

Also, change the `:has_one` in the Interaction model to a `:belongs_to`.

Comment: thanks!! this works- do you have any idea why in my example the first object gets the key though and the rest doesn't? 
as for :has_one and :belongs_to see the comments above

Comment: the belongs_to definitely has to be there. That is not questionable.  I'd bet that the way you have it now, something like `interation1.schedule` is going to throw an error.

Comment: As far as only the first interaction getting the key: Rails works in mysterious ways, especially when you do something wrong.  This won't be last time you'll see Rails do something weird, instead of just blowing up, when you make a mistake.

Comment: okay, you are right: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: schedules.interaction_id: